# <%= %> syntax in Typescript/Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm working on an Angular project that makes use of a variable called `WEB_HOST`. I can see in another file where the variable is defined (it's somehow defined in a class called `ProjectConfig`).

**Definition (simplified):**

```
export class ProjectConfig {
  WEB_HOST = 'https://example.com'; // I didn't think properties could be assigned here?

  constructor() { ... }
}
```

Now, from a completely separate *.ts file, this obviously doesn't work:

```
let x = WEB_HOST; // x is undefined
```

However, in the same file, some existing code manages to access the variable's value by using a bizarre string interpolation:

```
let x = `<%= WEB_HOST %>`; // x == 'https://example.com'
```

What is going on here? I've never seen this `<%=` syntax before. Is it part of Angular? Typescript? I haven't been able to find any documentation on what it does.

I also don't know how it manages to get a property out of `ProjectConfig` (and I'm not sure it's a class property either... the definition being outside of any class function confuses me too).

Comment: [Looks like ASP to me.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/k6xeyd4z(v=vs.100))

Comment: It's some kind of server-side templating language.  Possibly classic ASP.  Could be Webforms.

Comment: Variables that are replaced by your compilation or prerendering process.

Comment: It's clear that it's some kind of templating, but which one? Where can I find out and read the documentation so I know all the tricks it has up its sleeve?

Comment: @JohnAlexander That looks like ASP.  See Example: https://www.w3schools.com/asp/showasp.asp?filename=demo_syntax_tags

Comment: This can also be HAML. A template engine for Ruby on Rails http://haml.info/

Comment: We can't tell you which one specifically.  Several use that syntax.  What is the file extension of the file containing that markup?

Answer (score 0):

So, this is ASP Tags.

If you take a look at the following from w3schools.  https://www.w3schools.com/asp/showasp.asp?filename=demo_syntax_tags

You will see that it is used in the HTML for templating.  It can also be used I believe in other files as it is processed on the server before the client application runs on your browser.

HTH

Comment: There are other templating engines that use those tags.  There is no reason to be certain this is ASP.

Comment: Interesting. So it is getting preprocessed and rendering that variable's value into the Javascript when Angular compiles. Is it a separate install, or part of Angular? What is the scope it has access to?

Comment: @JohnAlexander It is completely unrelated to Angular or TypeScript.  No relationship.  You just happen to have a server-side system in use, and you also happen to be using Angular.  The scope is everything server-side.

Comment: @JohnAlexander when you visit a website, a lot of websites use that time to log information about you from the cookies you submitted, etc.  That being said, a website can use that as a time to fetch data related to said user.  They may fetch or set tokens, or in this case, prepopulate part of the Angular application with relevant information.  Maybe even Localization information etc.  Then the application is served to the client and after it is finished, runs.  Then the app would run with that given information.

Comment: @JohnAlexander Server side processing prior to an application running and displaying to a user is fairly common and there are a lot of ways to accomplish this.  Python, PHP, ASP all have different use cases, but their own separate frameworks in place to help with development.

Comment: So in the Chrome Source panel, it shows me the Typescript code, and that variable is still in there... not token-replaced with anything else. How does that work?

Comment: @JohnAlexander is this a different question?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like ERB, a Ruby templating engine that Ruby on Rails uses.
https://codingbee.net/tutorials/ruby/ruby-the-erb-templating-system

Others have mentioned that various languages use `<%= some_code_here %>` for templating.

Regardless of what language is processing it, I imagine your .ts file runs through some server side framework, that will put some string value in place of WEB_HOST, and then the .ts file will be transpiled to JS.

Answer (score -1):

You could try this way on HTML file

{{window.location.origin}}

if it doesn't recognize the window variable we might need this in ts file

declare const window;